# Changing Biopython include path for compilation during pip installation

Tags: python, numpy, include, pip, biopython

I'm trying to install Biopython (a python package) using PIP on my work machine (OpenSuse x86_64).

It all goes fine until it tries to do some compilation using numpy headers

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fPIC -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Bio/Cluster/clustermodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Bio/Cluster/clustermodule.o
```

At which point it fails

```
Bio/Cluster/clustermodule.c:2:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
```

This is because `numpy/arrayobject.h` is in

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/
```

and not

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
```

Is there a way to update whatever variable is setting the include path (to the `/local` version), either globally or explicitly for this installation?

**UPDATE**

Over a year later, I was faced with a similar problem, except this time the `.h` files simply didn't exist on my system. By just copying the `.h` from another machine into the

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy
```

directory installation went fine.

Comment: I'ld assume that the packaging for biopython is done wrong, cause it doesn't try import numpy and check for numpy.__file__
I suggest open a bug report.

Comment: It's possible my system is set up wrong too though - my numpy.__file__ points to '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/'

Comment: Did you try a local install as mentioned in [section 8](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html)? I just did a pip install --user biopython on my local machine which worked flawlessly. Of course in section 8 is not a pip install.

Comment: You can ask pip to download only, edit the paths in setup.py, and then install manually.

Comment: Alternatively, you can copy or link the relevant files so pip may find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Bort, I discovered this is, apparently a [known error](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html#htoc34) (local/user space installation wasn't working anyway).

By editing the Biopython `setup.py` file in the following places

### Original

```
#Add extensions that requires NumPy to build
if is_Numpy_installed():
   import numpy
   numpy_include_dir = numpy.get_include()
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.Cluster.cluster',
              ['Bio/Cluster/clustermodule.c',
               'Bio/Cluster/cluster.c'],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir],
              ))
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.KDTree._CKDTree',
              ["Bio/KDTree/KDTree.c",
               "Bio/KDTree/KDTreemodule.c"],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir],
              ))
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.Motif._pwm',
              ["Bio/Motif/_pwm.c"],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir],
              ))
```

### Updated

```
#Add extensions that requires NumPy to build
if is_Numpy_installed():
   import numpy
   numpy_include_dir = numpy.get_include()
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.Cluster.cluster',
              ['Bio/Cluster/clustermodule.c',
               'Bio/Cluster/cluster.c'],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir, '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/'],
              ))
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.KDTree._CKDTree',
              ["Bio/KDTree/KDTree.c",
               "Bio/KDTree/KDTreemodule.c"],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir, '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/'],
              ))
   EXTENSIONS.append(
      Extension('Bio.Motif._pwm',
              ["Bio/Motif/_pwm.c"],
              include_dirs=[numpy_include_dir, '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/'],
              ))
```

Then using pip to install from source (I re-compressed the folder with the updated `setup.py` file in it then ran)

```
pip install recompressed.tar.gz
```

and it's installed and good to go.

**Update**
I actually had a very similar problem with this on another openSUSE machine, but this time had no include files anywhere... To get around this I copied them across from the numpy source and fed them in using the include_dirs update above.

Comment: Just ooc, if you do a import numpy, print numpy.__file__ and print numpy.get_include(), do they point to different directories on your machine? I hope you are aware how badly [broken](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux) BLAS, numpy and scipy is in open_suse.

Comment: numpy.__file__ = /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc, numpy.get_include() = /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include.

I started using OpenSuse 4 days ago (after years with Ubuntu) and was not. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: So this is confusing now, your imported numpy is different from the one you build biopython against.... you should look into that. I am still stuck with suse due to the fact that one cannot change an entire department. However, we use only our own builds.

Comment: So the imported numpy folder lacks any of the .h include files, which all seem to be in the /usr/local/... directory instead of the /usr/lib64/.... I'm not sure if this is deliberate or not (the /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy folder has literally just two .txt files in it and nothing more.